# How to distribute a partnership K-1 (1065) other income item (line 11B) to heirs on a K-1 (1041)

Tags: united-states, income-tax, estate-tax

I have a partnership K-1 (1065) which shows an amount on the "other income" line (line 11B).  I am distributing this to the heirs, as the designated recipient died and I am the executor of the estate.  But the estate K-1 (1041) does not have a similar item.  Do I show this on the estate K-1 as "ordinary business income", "Other portfolio and nonbusiness income", or do I create a special "other information" line 14I entry?

Comment: There is not enough information to answer the question. _Who_ is the recipient of the partnership K-1? _You personally?_  If so, whose heirs are you talking about?

Comment: The estate of the deceased person is the recipient.  The heirs are the 3 people who inherit from the estate.